# Why is 0x8000000000000000LL considered unsigned long long by gcc?

Tags: c, gcc, types, literals

I am compiling a piece of code where the value of the `0x8000000000000000LL` literal is used to identify an unknown/unsupported value.

The `LL` suffix indicates that the value should be interpreted as a (`signed`) `long long` (`int`), but gcc (I have tried with 4.8.5 and 4.1.1) says that the value is of type `unsigned long long`.

I put a sample code here:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define UNKNOWN 0x8000000000000000LL

int main(void){
  long long value = 1000;

  if ((unsigned long long) value == UNKNOWN) {
    puts("Yes, they are different!!");
  }

  if (value == (long long) UNKNOWN) {
    puts("Yes, they are different!!");
  }

  if (value == UNKNOWN) {
    puts("Yes, they are different!!");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The result of the compilation with this command `gcc -Wsign-compare ll.c` is this:

```
ll.c: In function ‘main’:
ll.c:16:13: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
   if (value == UNKNOWN) {
             ^
```

Why is the `0x8000000000000000LL` literal value considered unsigned?

Comment: Because `0x8000000000000000` is too large to be represented by `long long`.

Comment: .... yet in range of `unsigned long long`.

Comment: Just because `LLONG_MIN` reinterpreted as a an an unsigned long long is  `0x8000000000000000` doesn't make  `LLONG_MIN` replaceable with `0x8000000000000000`. The types are different. Incidentally, `LLONG_MIN` is usually defined as `# define LLONG_MIN (-LLONG_MAX - 1LL)` just to escape these integer literal type promotion rules. (If `LLONG_MAX` is hexadecimal, then the hexadecimal that's one larger than `LLONG_MAX` would already jump to the next type (unsigned long long) and  (unary minus is applied after the fact)).

Comment: Now I finally got it, I was misinterpreting 0x8000000000000000LL literal as a bit representation, when it is an hexadecimal representation of a positive value. The 0x8000000000000000 bit representation corresponds to the **-**0x8000000000000000LL literal value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because that's how it works for integer literals that are hexadecimal or octal and don't fit into the integer type suggested by the suffix.

[6.4.4.1p5](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.1p5):

> The type of an integer constant is the first of the corresponding
>   list in which its value can be represented.

[image]

Notice that unlike decimal integer literals, hexadecimal and octal literals without the `u`/`U` suffix can, when searching for a suitable type, flip the type sign before ascending to the next higher-ranking signed integer type.

Comment: Yes and now. There is no such warning with clang or Visual Studio.

Comment: Oh thanks, I didn't know... Seriously... Of course warnings are optional, clang ones are usually far better than gcc and more frequent for real issues.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher clang has the warnign too. But it's not in `-Wall`. You have to pass `-Wextra` or `-Wsign-compare` explicitly. (It's the same for gcc, actuall. At least with my versions of gcc and clang.)

Comment: gcc warns on signs with just `-Wall`. But perhaps indeed, clang put it behind an additional level. For VS, it's a level 3, so only if I have /W3, but no warnings, even on /permissive-.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher, no you need -Wextra in gcc to include the sign-compare warning.

Comment: gcc `-Wextra` provides `-Wclobbered -Wempty-body -Wignored-qualifiers -Wmissing-field-initializers -Wmissing-parameter-type (C only) -Wold-style-declaration (C only) -Woverride-init -Wsign-compare -Wtype-limits` (and several others when used in conjunction with `-Wall`). Note: on clang, you can also use `-Weverything` (for literally everything)